# LexikJWT get user profile by token

Tags: symfony, profile, lexikjwtauthbundle

Using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle, FOSRest, FOSUser how do I get authenticated user profile by token. Is it possible?

So let's say user is already authenticated via LexikJWT and I have an api endpoint like `/api/profile` where I send the token and I expect to get specified user data.

I'm using for frontend ReactJS with Redux.

Comment: not sure if understand your question - when your token is an instance of TokenInterface what does $token->getUser() provide?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an example of how to get your user by a service when the user is already authenticated:

```
class UserService
{

    /** @var  TokenStorageInterface */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @param TokenStorageInterface  $storage
     */
    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $storage,
    )
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $storage;
    }

    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        if ($token instanceof TokenInterface) {

            /** @var User $user */
            $user = $token->getUser();
            return $user;

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `services.yml`:

```
tenant_user_service:
    class: YourBundle\YourPackage\UserService
    arguments: [ '@security.token_storage' ]
```

This will return your user - but be aware depending on the how user got set to the token during authentication this can be as well only your username as a string. But basically you get any content from your current $token->getUser().

Comment: thanks for feedback! I'm still not able to understand your point. So the scenario would be: having protected route to `api/profile` user authenticate itself and via react routing making a request to profile route and as response should get back some user specific data, like avatar etc.. At this point how my Controller knows about user?

Comment: controller should know user by: `$this->getUser()` which is a shortcut in every Symfony's controller which is extended and used the 'standard way'

Comment: yes you are right, but I had my controller as service declared and I needed to inject `@security.token_storage`

Answer (score 0):

i'm new but i can try...

you can use the annotation like

```
@Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER')")
```

in your controller and something like`$this->getUser()->getUsername();` to get the username.

example:

```
$user = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
    ->FindOne($this->getUser()->getUsername());`
```

after that you serialize datas, create new Response and return it.