# How to return user data in API Platform JWT auth

Tags: symfony, jwt, api-platform.com

I have a difficulty, and I've been wandering around the internet for a while looking for the solution.

I'm using API Platform with JWT authentication, following the steps in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/ and it works really well. But I need to know if I can return the user data in the response, along with the Token, because I need to use it in the frontend. I really can't find how to do it, neither in the official documentation, nor by analyzing the bundle itself.

Is there any way?

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192877/lexikjwt-get-user-profile-by-token/42201281#42201281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is best practice, but you could create a custom Event Listener, one that uses the Lexik Authentication Success. That returns the token information

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;

class LoginSuccessListener
{

    public function onLoginSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $payload = $event->getData();
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }
        // Add information to user payload
        $payload['user'] = [
            ...
        ];
        $event->setData($payload);
    }
}
```

And then in your services.yaml, you'll need to register the Listener

```
#services.yaml    
App\EventListener\LoginSuccessListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.on_authentication_success, method: onLoginSuccess }
```